# ResourceNotFoundException in Android

Tags: android, resources, android-2.2-froyo

My app works fine on Android 3+ but when I run against the 2.2 emulator, I am getting the following FC:

```
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:321)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  ... 35 more
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_medium_white.xml from drawable resource ID #0x0
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:327)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  ... 39 more
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_medium_white.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x0
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1924)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1692)
03-08 18:15:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(342):  ... 42 more
```

This line: 
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_medium_white.xml

says this resource is not being found... but this resource should be provide by the android api right?

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: no i don;e think so. you need to have `progress_medium_white.xml` under drawable folder

Comment: why does it work on Android 3+ then?

Comment: you can check if there is one under the androd resource drawable folder

Comment: Probably, it has been added in 3.0+, so, it doesn't find it on prior API Levels

Comment: no, there is not this resource. apk for Android 3+ and android 2x is the same, so if the resource is there or not is irrelevant right? I mean, if it works on 3+, it should work on 2+ too in regarding of resources

Comment: @ArtooDetoo so I understand...but the compatibility lib doesn't cover this kind of stuff?

Comment: i did check the source it is there for 4.0.3. gotta check for below 11 http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/progress_medium_white.xml?av=f

Comment: No... It "only" provides fragments (excluding Preferences) and other `code-related` features. But nothing stops you from copying the missing graphics to your /res/drawables-XYZ folders... just hijack the graphics and use them ;)

Comment: I'll give it a try.. the thing is, I am not even using the progress_medium_white.xml in my project :S

Comment: post your xml coz your stacktrace says `Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Comment: put from which file? <unknown> is not a file :P

Comment: check your xml's it says line 17.

Comment: I have more than 30 layout xml's in my project. The error doesn't say which one....it says <unknown>

Comment: You often have to read further into Android crash traces. In your case, further down it is quite clear about the problem: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_medium_white.xml from drawable resource ID #0x0`

Comment: I know, but I don't use that drawable anywhere in my code. I also tried adding a dummy xml drawable with this name bit I still get the same error